# CSS style :nth-child even nested elements

Tags: html, css

How can I style `:nth-child(4n)` even with the element is **nested inside a div**, example here is `p` inside `div`:

```css
p:nth-child(2) {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<div>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
</div>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: In that case, you would need `nth-of-type`.

Comment: @Abhitalks when I do p:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: red;
} I have the third p in red

Comment: Ooops! I misread the markup in haste. This answer might help you -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/23987180/1355315

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS nth-of-type selector with nested elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986929/css-nth-of-type-selector-with-nested-elements)

Comment: which paragraph you need to style ? ( second or fourth ) ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .content *:nth-child(2) {
        background: red;
    }
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
<div class="content">
    <p>The first paragraph.</p>
    <div>
        <p>The second paragraph.</p>
    </div>
    <p>The third paragraph.</p>
    <p>The fourth paragraph.</p>

    <p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body p:nth-child(2n) {
    background: red;
}
body div:nth-child(2n) p {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<div>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
</div>
<p>The third paragraph.</p>
<p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
<body>
```